# Rename partition and set new location hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Need to rename partition and set the new location for an external table all in one statement.

```sql
alter table A partition(part='A') rename to partition (part='B');
alter table A partition(part='B') set location 's3://...';
```

I am trying to see if this can be combined in to single statement

```sql
alter table A partition(part='A') rename to partition(part='B') set location 's3://'..'
```

Comment: ¿Do you want to set a new location for the table or for the partitions?

Comment: @TsvetelinaMariyanova . I want to set it for the partitions.